# How do I get current value (share price,exchange rate, temperature) and use it in a script?

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension for a continuous update of temperature or share prices or exchange rate. What are the simplest methods to get such data from the web(similar to how we do a google search and find the temperature of a city or something)?

Comment: Depends on the site, but basically it's XMLHttpRequest + DOMParser. You can find tons of examples.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to pay and use an API?

Comment: Again, depends on the site, obviously.

Comment: I am not understanding what you mean to say. Can you elaborate depends on site part?

Comment: Well, my point is that you can easily find examples using the two keywords I mentioned.